# Gradle dependencies update

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

One of the advantages of using Gradle in Android Studio is that it helps in dependency management. So if I have used a particular version of a library in my `build.gradle` file,
then how will I force it to update the dependency version once the higher version is available?

Some of the dependencies in my build.gradle are specified as

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':facebookSDK')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/crouton-1.8.1.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> One of the advantages of using Gradle in Android Studio is that it helps in dependency management.

Not the way that you are using it.

> So if i have used a particular version of a library in my build.gradle file, then how will i force it to update the dependency version once the higher version is available?

In your case, you would download the new JARs, put them in `libs/`, and update your `build.gradle` to match.

The preferred approach is for you to delete those JARs and replace your two `compile files` statements with ones that pull down the dependencies from Maven Central or another artifact repository. You can find the proper statements for popular open source libraries like those via the [Gradle, please](http://gradleplease.appspot.com/) site.

In your case, you would use:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.3'
compile 'de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.5'
```

These will require you to also have a `repositories` closure as a peer to your `dependencies` closure:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

This may already exist.

These `compile` statements still pin you to a specific version of those libraries, but moving to a new version would be a simple matter of updating the `compile` statement, and Gradle will pull down the new dependency on your next build.

If you want, you could replace part of the version number with a wildcard (e.g., `2.3.+`). This will cause Gradle to automatically update to new patchlevels of the library, in this case. Some developers do not approve of this approach, as while it is convenient, it does reduce your ability to be able to reproduce a build (e.g., you need to recompile some older branch of your code, and now you don't know what version of the artifact you were using back then).

Comment: Perfect answer (as ever @CommonsWare). But recently, my gradle doesn't highlight the libraries that have new version in the repository, and that is a powerfull feature for me.

Comment: @wendigo: I am not aware that Gradle ever "highlights" libraries newer than what you ask for. If you use wildcards, it will automatically grab them; if you do not use wildcards, it ignores them. There's a plugin for Gradle that will give you a report of available updates to dependencies, though I forget where I saw it.

Comment: I'll add this answer too : http://stackoverflow.com/a/35371234/2057809

Having gradle doing dependencies update is cool, but it's even more usefull when it can also detect automatically which dependencies need to be updated.

Answer (score 3):

As you are compiling files from your local project, I don't think you can automatically compile a new individual jar version if available. What you can do instead of compiling individual files is:

`compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')`

This will compile all jars in the libs directory so you will always have the latest version.

Both the libraries you are using are available to be compiled as dependencies from mavencentral.

```
compile 'de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.5'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.3'
```

If you want to ensure you are getting the latest versions is you use a plus in place of the version number. It's up to you how open you want to be with this.. so

```
compile 'de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.+'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.+'
```

will give you the latest version under the 1. or 2. versioning cycles...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. @CommonsWare has already given a perfect answer.

Comment: This is not something i'll not recommend : having an automatic update for dependencies means to loose an easy way to control which version is currently installed. For corrections update, it can be, but for minor update this is kinda unsafe.

Comment: @Aldo If you read the answer, I am not recommending always using the latest dependencies, I am just informing that it is possible if it is something that is required. This answers the question correctly and does not deserve to be voted down.

Comment: @domji84 well wasn't really obvious :( But i agree with you, my vote down was a little bit harsh, i'm sorry. I edited your answer to put a new vote up after :)

Answer (score 0):

> - If you want, you could **replace part of the version number with a wildcard (e.g., 2.3.+).**
> - This **will cause Gradle to automatically update to new patch-levels of the library**, in this case.
> - **Some developers do not approve of this approach**, as while it is convenient **it does reduce your ability to be able to reproduce a build** (e.g., you need to recompile some older branch of your code, and now you don't know what version of the artifact you were using back then).

I have found [Gradle, please](https://gradleplease.appspot.com/) to be my answer here.

- Easily get the latest android library gradle compile statement.