# How to find newer upgrades on all libraries in gradle

Tags: gradle

How to find newer upgrades on all libraries in gradle. I have the following dependencies in mybuild.gradle file, how do I find out what newer upgrades are available?

```
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.3'
testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3'
testCompile 'org.jmockit:jmockit:1.18'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a way to detect the latest version of a dependency, it is not built into Gradle by default. There does appear to be a plugin that can help.

See this post:

[How to check if gradle dependency has new version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683327/how-to-check-if-gradle-dependency-has-new-version)

Comment: You should really flag original question as duplicate and include the link to the other SO question instead of posting an answer.

Comment: Thanks, good idea. Got it.

Answer (score 3):

Gradle doesn't have an out of the box, but you can use the excellent [gradle-versions-plugin](https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin)

```
plugins {
  id "com.github.ben-manes.versions" version "0.12.0"
}
```

and from there on run `gradle dependencyUpdates`. The plugin also supports results in xml and json in addition to the standard plain text.

Comment: Latest version is up to '0.39.0'

Answer (score 0):

Gradle uses the same version syntax as ivy.

http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/dependency.html#revision

Where you can do something like:

```
testCompile 'org.jmockit:jmockit:1.+'
```

Comment: Will this fail if it is upgraded to a higher major version (say 2.x). I just want to run a command and I want that to tell me that the latest versions are as follows

Comment: So you are doing a build. Commonly, you don't want to have your dependencies automatically upgraded, which could create issues with your code if the API changes. The line I provide means you are ok with any version of jmockit v. 1.0 or any other 1. version... 1.5, 1.8, etc.

Comment: I am unaware of any built in Grdle function that will print the latest revisions of a dependency, which means it would be polling the repository for all revisions.