# Android dependencies and repositories

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, jcenter

I'm an Android developer for a couple of years and I'm used to put the version of my dependencies on hold and not update for two or three months. Then I take a day to hunt the latest versions, download and test them one by one.

But I got spoiled with new langages and tools, where some library is almost automatically updated and my continuos delivery environment tests it almost efortless.

And this makes me think why there's no equivalent for Android? Android Studio does tells me when there are new updates of the platform and build tools, but not the dependences. And many times when I go to [JFrog (JCenter)](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter) it's really hard to find a package and get it's latest version number.

So, my question is: does anybody has a more 21st century menthod to update your dependencies?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can tell Gradle to update more _rigorously_, but you typically don't want to do that incase incompatibilities are leaked that completely break your App and you would have no idea. Using `+` in the version name for example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if gradle dependency has new version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683327/how-to-check-if-gradle-dependency-has-new-version)