# What's the last version of Android Volley?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley

I'm very sorry to ask this very simple question, but it's more than half hour that I'm trying to find the last version of Android Volley.

Here: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html I found

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
}
```

But I'm sure that's not the last version. Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683327/how-to-check-if-gradle-dependency-has-new-version) did not help since it didn't show any updates for volley.

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As Farooq Khan pointed out, the current release is at  **https://github.com/google/volley/releases**.

The latest version as of *December 15, 2017* is "**1.1.0**".

so the gradle string for android apps would be

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
```

Now you should use `Implementation` instead of `Compile` because in latest version of gradle `compile` is now **obsolete**.

by the way, version 1.1.1 is also being prepared,
as per https://github.com/google/volley/wiki/Release-Notes

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted this, but I think this is the correct answer as of now

Comment: Version 1.1.1 is available now. So, use:
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'

Answer (score 9):

The 1.0.0 is the official released version of android volley currently. It was released in Dec 2016. Here is the [link of volley project](https://github.com/google/volley/releases).

Comment: @FractalBob See the releases here: https://github.com/google/volley/releases

Comment: Thanks, Farooq. Your answer should be marked as the correct one.