# Get warning in IntelliJ IDEA if Gradle dependecy is obsoete

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

We can get warnings of obsolete Gradle dependencies in Android Studio as showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683327/how-to-check-if-gradle-dependency-has-new-version), but I can't make it work for a pure Java project in IntelliJ IDEA.

Is it possible to have the same functionality in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41958982/2000323

Comment: Yeah, I am using it, I just wanted ti more integrated with IntelliJ, as Android Studio does (warning and auto-set new version)