# What's the gradle equivalent of npm-outdated?

Tags: gradle, build

I'd like to keep my `build.gradle` dependencies up to date. With Node.js, I run the [`npm outdated`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/outdated.html) (and later `npm update`).

What's the closest for Gradle?

[I don't mean for Android IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683327/how-to-check-if-gradle-dependency-has-new-version); I mean running it in the console for any project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle does **not** provide such a functionality **out of the box**.

You can check out the [Gradle Versions Plugin](https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin), as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41958982/3950370) of the question you linked. Please note, that this plugin does not update the dependencies, but generates a report describing possible updates.

The corresponding Github page also shows a link to the [Gradle Use Latest Versions Plugin](https://github.com/patrikerdes/gradle-use-latest-versions-plugin), which provides a task called `useLatestVersions` with the functionality you requested.