# Is there an equivalent for "npm outdated" / "npm audit" in Maven?

Tags: java, maven, security, npm

npm provides two useful commands for detecting outdated libraries:

- [npm outdated](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-outdated) checks your `package.json` / `package-lock.json` for outdated libraries
- [npm audit](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-audit) runs a security audit; it only reports libraries with known vulnerabilities

**Is there something equivalent in Maven for Java?**

---

Notes:

- [According to this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55839704/783510), Gradle does not support the `npm outdated`-functionality out-of-the-box, but there is the [Grade Versions Plugin](https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin). Perhaps the equivalent [Versions Maven Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) could be used to used to provide `npm outdated`-like functionality, but I did not see that it can warn about security issues.
- I am aware of solutions to integrate vulnerability scanning of the code in the CI systems, but I am looking for a simple mechanism like `npm` provides that does not require a lot of setup.

Comment: versions-maven-plugin is intended for your equivalent of `npm outdated` and for `npm audit` you have to do some setup because there are so many different services available (snyk, sonatype, owasp, SonarQube etc.)

Comment: For `npm audit` check https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/index.html