# Android Studio doesn't give new version warning for dependencies when using variables?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies, build.gradle

How do I make it so I get helpful warnings when I store the version number as a variable as I do when I write the version number straight into the dependency declaration? Tried looking in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683327/how-to-check-if-gradle-dependency-has-new-version) thread but don't see a solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are some plugins..
https://jmfayard.github.io/refreshVersions/
https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin

I personally prefer first one. Althouhg there are some minor issues.