# Android Studio Not Showing Suggested Gradle Dependency Updates With Lint

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea, lint

## Expected

After enabling *Newer Library Versions Available* under Preferences, Lint will show recommended Gradle dependency/library updates in the *build.gradle* files.

## Actual

Lint is not showing recommended Gradle dependency/library updates in the *build.gradle* files. There are many recommended updates as shown under the Project Structure Suggestions.

i.e. Menu: *File* > *Project Structure...* > *Suggestions*

[image: Suggestions For Updates]

## Configuration

The library version numbers are saved as variables in the application level *build.gradle* file.

Application-level *build.gradle*

```
buildscript {
    ext.build_gradle_version = '4.1.2'
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.21'
    ext.fragment_version = '1.2.4'
    ...
    
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$build_gradle_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        ...
    }
}
```

Project-level *build.gradle*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
...

android {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragment_version"
    ...
}
```

**Settings**

- *Preferences* > *Editor* > *Inspections* > *Newer Library Versions Available*

[image: Enable Newer Library Versions Available]

**Android Studio**

- Android Studio 4.2.1
- Build #AI-202.7660.26.42.7351085, built on May 10, 2021
- Runtime version: 11.0.8+10-b944.6916264 x86_64
- VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by N/A
- macOS 10.16
- GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
- Memory: 2048M
- Cores: 16
- Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
- Non-Bundled Plugins: com.android.tool.sizereduction.plugin, com.thoughtworks.gauge, mobi.hsz.idea.gitignore, org.jetbrains.kotlin, com.developerphil.adbidea, com.google.mad-scorecard, cn.wjdghd.unique.plugin.id

Comment: Thanks! In my case `build.gradle` shows updates with or without enabled option "Newer Library Versions Available". But `Suggestions` show updates in `app` module, not `<All modules>`. https://prnt.sc/132i0lg

Comment: I have a feeling the issue I posted has to do with the usage of library version variables in the *build.gradle* files.

Answer (score -1):

The lint tool on build.gradle doesn't have knowledge of the variables value. If you would like to declare variables for your dependencies you can update your dependencies and their related variables via project structure:
Preferences > Project Structure
[Example of how to update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubzY0.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Going through the project structure and manually updating the dependencies doesn't solve the underlying issue which is that the build.gradle file is not showing the lint warnings (even for dependencies with no variable value)